# PHP ElasticSearch how to set mapping before indexing records?

Tags: php, indexing, elasticsearch, laravel-5, mapping

I'm using laravel and [elasticsearch-php](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php) to index and store data to elastic, my problem is that elastisearch uses from dynamic mapping but I need to set my custom mapping. How can I use from my mapping?

Bellow is my code:

```
$client = \Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->build();

        $mappingData = array(
            'index' => 'promote_kmp',
            'body' => array(
                'mappings' => $resource->getMappingProperties()
            )
        );
        $client->indices()->create($mappingData);

        $params = [
            'type' => 'resources',
            'id' => uniqid(),
            'body' => [
                'id' => $resource->id,
                'name' => $resource->name,
                'display_name_en' => $resource->display_name_en,
                'display_name_pr' => $resource->display_name_pr,
                'display_name_pa' => $resource->display_name_pa,
                'table_name'      => $resource->table_name,
                'model_name'      => $resource->model_name,
                'in_sidemenu'     => $resource->in_sidemenu,
                'icon_class'      => $resource->icon_class,
                'created_at'      => $resource->created_at,
                'created_by'      => $user,
            ]
        ];

        //$response = $client->indices()->create($resource->getMappingProperties());

        $client->index($params);
```

`$resource->getMappingProperties()` get the mapping array I have set in model.
but when I want to index a record it says `IndexAlreadyExistsException[[promote_kmp] already exists]`. This question arise when I want to search for date field searching is not properly working and I guess that mapping is not true.

Comment: That exception is thrown when the Index already exists (no shit sherlock :P). So I'm thinking that you have that duplicated, the first part should only be executed once. Are you executing that several times?

Comment: @mloureiro Yeah you are right, but where I should write the first part, in laravel model class or ...? or with another option if i set mapping data inside params, how i can force elastic to use this mapping?

Comment: In my case I've made a "setup" that is ran, like migrations in laravel, because you want to prepare *elasticsearch database* then you just want to query/insert stuff.

Comment: @mloureiro Means like a class with autoload? or something else?

Comment: *class with autoload* think as a normal DB, you will only run the `create table`'s only once. So here you should do the same, manually, automatically with a command or a "installation script"

Comment: I would probably go for the command. looks easier and you can set it onto the composer.json post-install commands, and it will set your system ready for use

Answer (score 0):

As I was saying in comments.

The code is executing the creation of index every time you want to query.
But the index must be created only once.

So it should work like the migration for the DB's.

The only idea I can give you is to make a command to generate the index.
So that you could just

```
$ artisan elasticsearch:generate <index>
```

---

About the code, what I've done for our case, made the index with a way to inject the types, plus a way to create them into elasticsearch:

```
interface Index {

  /**
   * @param Type[] $types Index types (resources)
   */
  function setTypes(array $types);

  /**
   * Generate the index and the types into the elasticsearch
   */
  function create();

}
```

Then the types should generate the mappings and the type name (as `/<index>/<type>`, like:

```
interface Type {

  /**
   * @return string The type name
   */
   function getName();

  /**
   * @return array The type mapping 
   */
  function getMapping();

}
```

So (somewhere), you would create the class (this could be better):

```
$myIndex = new MyIndex();
$myIndex->setTypes([
  new MyFirstType(),
  new MySecondType(),
  //...
]);
$myIndex->create();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: So with this solution where i should put my mapping data? because inside one index i have multiple resource and each resource with its unique mapping

Comment: In my case I created a class for the Index that would inject a list of all the *resources* that, that index will have, and generate it there

Comment: Means you defined the resources, and mapping inside that class, and one you run from command line an index for all the resources your defined in, is created?