# ElasticSearch how to search comma separated string inside comma separated fields?

Tags: php, search, indexing, elasticsearch

In a case I should search a comma separated string against a comma separated fields, because of this I do the following in mapping but show `MapperParsingException[Analyzer [comma] not found for field [conduct_days]]` error.

```
            $course = new Course();
            $course->no = '1231321';
            .......
            .......
            $course->save();

            // Now index the new created course

            $client = \Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->build();




            $params = [
                'index' => 'my_index',
                'type' => 'my_resources',
                'body' => [
                    'my_resources' => [
                        '_source' => [
                            'enabled' => true
                        ],
                        'settings' => [
                            "analysis" => [
                                "tokenizer" => [
                                    "comma" => [
                                        "type" => "pattern",
                                        "pattern" => ","
                                    ]
                                ],
                                "analyzer" => [
                                    "comma" => [
                                        "type" => "custom",
                                        "tokenizer" => "comma"
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                        'properties' => [
                            'conduct_days' => array(
                                'type' => 'string',
                                'analyzer' => 'comma'
                            ),
                            'no' => array(
                                'type' => 'string',
                                'analyzer' => 'standard'
                            ),
                            'created_at' => array(
                                'type' => 'date_time',
                                "format"=>"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||MM/dd/yyyy||yyyy/MM/dd"
                            ),
                            'updated_at' => array(
                                'type' => 'date_time',
                                "format" => "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||MM/dd/yyyy||yyyy/MM/dd"
                            ),
                            'deleted_at' => array(
                                'type' => 'date_time',
                                "format" => "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||MM/dd/yyyy||yyyy/MM/dd"
                            ),
                            'created_by' => array(
                                'type' => 'string',
                                'analyzer' => 'standard'
                            ),
                            'updated_by' => array(
                                'type' => 'string',
                                'analyzer' => 'standard'
                            ),
                            'deleted_by' => array(
                                'type' => 'string',
                                'analyzer' => 'standard'
                            )
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ];

            // Update the index mapping
            $client->indices()->putMapping($params);

            $params = [
                'index' => 'promote_kmp',
                'type' => 'courses',
                'id' => uniqid(),
                'body' => [
                    'id'                      => $course->id,
                    'conduct_days'            => $course->conduct_days,
                    'no'                      => $course->no,
                    'created_at'              => $course->created_at,
                    'created_by'              => $loggedInUser,
                ]
            ];
            $client->index($params);
```

Suppose I have to search `1,3,5,7` inside the conduct days fields that can has `1,2` and `1,2,3`, and `1,3,5,6` and many more. For search I think I should explode the search term for example If search term is `1,2`, I should search two time, first for `1` and then for `2`. Any other solution for searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass `settings` inside the `putMapping` call, they will be ignored. `settings` is meant to be passed to `create` call to create an index

```
    $params = [
        'index' => 'my_index',
        'body' => [
                    'settings' => [
                        "analysis" => [
                            "tokenizer" => [
                                "comma" => [
                                    "type" => "pattern",
                                    "pattern" => ","
                                ]
                            ],
                            "analyzer" => [
                                "comma" => [
                                    "type" => "custom",
                                    "tokenizer" => "comma"
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
        ]
    ];

    $response = $client->indices()->create($params);
```

Then you can call `putMapping` with the mapping type definition but without the `settings`:

```
        $params = [
            'index' => 'my_index',
            'type' => 'my_resources',
            'body' => [
                'my_resources' => [
                    '_source' => [
                        'enabled' => true
                    ],
                    'properties' => [
                        'conduct_days' => array(
                            'type' => 'string',
                            'analyzer' => 'comma'
                        ),
                        'no' => array(
                            'type' => 'string',
                            'analyzer' => 'standard'
                        ),
                        'created_at' => array(
                            'type' => 'date_time',
                            "format"=>"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||MM/dd/yyyy||yyyy/MM/dd"
                        ),
                        'updated_at' => array(
                            'type' => 'date_time',
                            "format" => "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||MM/dd/yyyy||yyyy/MM/dd"
                        ),
                        'deleted_at' => array(
                            'type' => 'date_time',
                            "format" => "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||MM/dd/yyyy||yyyy/MM/dd"
                        ),
                        'created_by' => array(
                            'type' => 'string',
                            'analyzer' => 'standard'
                        ),
                        'updated_by' => array(
                            'type' => 'string',
                            'analyzer' => 'standard'
                        ),
                        'deleted_by' => array(
                            'type' => 'string',
                            'analyzer' => 'standard'
                        )
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];

        // Update the index mapping
        $client->indices()->putMapping($params);
```

**UPDATE**

However, in your case, I think the best thing to do is to create an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) which contains the settings (i.e. analyzers) and the mappings. Then all your app has to care about is simply to call `index()` to index the new Course documents. ES will take care of creating the index and mapping at the right time, i.e. the first time you index your first Course document.

Note that in order to do this, you need to

1. remove your current index and the `indices->create()` and `indices->putMapping()` calls in your code
2. create the index template using the /head/ plugin or Sense or simply a curl
3. only call `index()` from within your code

Comment: But because I should create mapping many times, for example inside create action, update, and delete how should I create index that should created one time. For now I change my code like the one you said shows this error `IndexAlreadyExistsException[[promote_kmp] already exists]`.

Comment: Usually, you create an index and a mapping type and then you don't have to anymore. You may delete the index before creating it again by using `$response = $client->indices()->delete(['index' => 'promote_kmp']);`. Then you can call `create` again.

Comment: But by deleting index, Is data safe? I think I will lose the indexed documents.

Comment: Then I don't understand why you want to re-apply the mapping several times. If your mapping is stable, you create an index, put a mapping and then you can make your queries.

Comment: Because of a reason like storing all user action related data (not to update the documents, every time insert new document), I'm using `ElasticSearch-PHP` with laravel, but I want to not use from dynamic mapping, and I should create my own mapping, so every time before indexing new document, I should do mapping, and If I want to create mapping once, where I should do that? where I should create mapping?

Comment: You don't have to create a mapping before indexing every new document. Only once before you index your first document. Your mileage may vary, but usually you create an index and mapping type only when your application starts.

Comment: It means I should Check first if an index is created before or no? and if index has been created before, just want to update the mapping portion.

Comment: It seems you already had a very related issue yesterday, which seems to have been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837260/php-elasticsearch-how-to-set-mapping-before-indexing-records Is it not working?

Comment: Yeah, but I'm confused with that. and implemented my own solution and working, but now in a case encountered that I should create custom analyzer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101042/discussion-between-jones-and-val).